# How to write content to file on linux SFTP server using SshClient?

Tags: linux, ssh.net

I am dealing with Linux SFTP server using .Net (SshClient) code, so I am creating folder on SFTP server and creating files also. For this I am using following code,

```
using (var client = new SshClient(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SftpServer"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SftpUserName"], WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SftpPassword"]))
{
   client.Connect();

    if (client.IsConnected)
    {
        //  Check if the Folder Already Exists 
        var ifExists = client.RunCommand("cat /etc/passwd  | grep -w " + ftpUserName);
        // If the Folder and User Does Not exists , create both 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ifExists.Result))
        {
            client.RunCommand("echo Asdf@123 | sudo -S mkdir /sftpusers/" + ftpUserName);
            client.RunCommand("echo Asdf@123 | sudo -S mkdir /sftpusers/" + ftpUserName + "/import"); //  this is for creating folder
            client.RunCommand("echo Asdf@123 | sudo -S mkdir /sftpusers/" + ftpUserName + "/schema");
            client.RunCommand("echo Asdf@123 | sudo -S touch /sftpusers/" + ftpUserName + "/schema/fileName.txt");
            sftpCreated = true;
        }
    }
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

This code is working file to create a folder and text files on SFTP but Now I am trying to write data to that file, and for that I am using following code,

```
client.RunCommand("echo Asdf@123 | sudo -S echo hi user >> /sftpusers/asb/schema/filename.txt");
```

But it is not working. I am getting error says `Error = "bash: /sftpusers/asb/schema/filename.txt: Permission denied\n`.

I am little confused that, if same command i.e. `echo pwd | sudo -s cmd`
is creating folder, files on SFTP server then why it failing while writing content to file.

Need help on this as early as possible.

Comment: Btw, your code has nothing to do with SFTP.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo touch ./blabla
```

Will create a `blabla` file as root with root(!) permissions. The owner of this file will be root and most probably the write will be only allowed for root.

```
sudo echo 123 > ./blabla
```

This will execute `echo` as root, and redirect the output to `blabla` as the shell(!) user. `sudo` makes the command `echo` run as root. But the redirection `>` is done by the shell, not by `sudo`. So the redirection is done by the however opened the shell, in your case by a user that isn't root, who can't access the file.

You have to write to the file as root for it to work. You can run a subshell as root:

```
echo 123 | sudo sh -c 'cat > ./blabla'
// or better for scripting, cause no double quoting is needed
echo 123 | sudo sh -c 'cat > "$1"' -- ./blabla
```

This will `echo 123` and execute `sh` as root with the command `cat` redirected to the first argument of the script, that is `blabla`. Note that as the shell is run as root, the redirection is also done as root, so the shell is able to open and write to the file.

Alternatively a more clean approach is to make a `tee`.

```
echo 123 | sudo tee blabla >/dev/null
```

Remember to redirect `tee`'s stdout to null, so it doesn't print anything.

Do:

```
 client.RunCommand("echo Asdf@123 | sudo -S sh -c 'echo hi user >> "$1"' -- /sftpusers/asb/schema/filename.txt");
```

Note that because you use `sudo -S` to read the password (which is unsafe and kind of bad), you can't use stdin to pass written string to `tee`.