# How to write formatted JSON to text file using ssh.net?

Tags: c#, json.net, ssh.net

I am writing a c# object as JSON to text file which is on SFTP server using ssh.net.

I am able to write it but double quotes are getting removed from Json property, How to persist it?

```
  using (var client = new SshClient(sftpServer, sftpUserName, sftpPassword))
        {
            client.Connect();

            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                //  Check if the Folder Already Exists 
                var ifExists = client.RunCommand("cat /etc/passwd  | grep -w " + directoryName);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ifExists.Result))
                {
                    var fileExist = client.RunCommand("cat /etc/passwd | find /sftpusers/" + directoryName + "/schema -name " + fileName + ".txt");
                    if (fileExist != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExist.Result))
                    {
                        client.RunCommand("echo " + sftpPassword + " | sudo -S touch /sftpusers/" + directoryName + "/schema/" + fileName + ".txt");
                    }
                    var jsonData = "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"asb\",\"namespace\":\"Employee\",\"Fields\":[{\"name\":\"PurchaseId\",\"type\":\"numeric\",\"ClientFieldNm\":null,\"ImportFieldLenQty\":0,\"ImportRetainFlag\":false,\"ImportPrimaryKeyFlag\":0,\"ImportResolveFKFieldFlag\":0,\"ImportDeblankDataFlag\":false,\"ImportEncryptFlag\":false,\"ImportBatIndexFlag\":false,\"ImportEnforceValidTypeFlag\":false,\"ImportRequiredFlag\":false}]}";
                    var query = string.Format("echo Asdf@123 | sudo -S sh -c 'echo {0} > $1' -- /sftpusers/test/schema/{1}.txt",jsonData, fileName);
                    client.RunCommand(query);

                }
            }
            client.Disconnect();
        }
```

Rather than using string Newtosoft json serializer but is also as above string is working.

Current data in filename.txt:

```
{type:record,name:asb,namespace:Employee,Fields:[{name:PurchaseId,type:numeric,ClientFieldNm:null,ImportFieldLenQty:0,ImportRetainFlag:false,ImportPrimaryKeyFlag:0,ImportResolveFKFieldFlag:0,ImportDeblankDataFlag:false,ImportEncryptFlag:false,ImportBatIndexFlag:false,ImportEnforceValidTypeFlag:false,ImportRequiredFlag:false}]}
```

Expected data in filename.txt:

```
{
"type":"record",
 "name":"asb",
 "namespace":"Employee",
  Fields[{
  "name":"PurchaseId",
  "type":"numeric",
  "ClientFieldNm":null,
  "ImportFieldLenQty":0,
  "ImportRetainFlag":false,
  "ImportPrimaryKeyFlag":0,
  "ImportResolveFKFieldFlag":0,
  "ImportDeblankDataFlag":false,
  "ImportEncryptFlag":false,
  "ImportBatIndexFlag":false,
  "ImportEnforceValidTypeFlag":false
  ,"ImportRequiredFlag":false
 }]}
```

Comment: It's the second question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/55529974/850848) you have asked (although under a different username), where you hack remote file access using shell commands, because you try to use `sudo`. It's about the time you realize that this is just a wrong way. -- Not to mention that you do not even try to explain why you use this strange approach in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really use `echo` for that. Use the `SftpClient` on that library (instead of the `SshClient`) to upload the actual file to the remote server.

But otherwise, you need to escape the quotes for the shell command, so try something like:

```
jsonData = jsonData.Replace(@"""", @"\""");
```

Before echoing it out.

Note that the way you are performing your command, if your `jsonData` contains a single quote (`'`), you'll also need to escape it (otherwise, it'll look to the shell like the end of the `'echo {0} > $1'` part of your command